# Animation transition between ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

Please see the two screenshots :

The top part seems to be using a ViewPager. The current screen on the ViewPager shows partial of the previous and next screens.

**Question** : How do we achieve this animation ? i.e. where partial of the previous ane next screens can be seen ??

[image]

Comment: Check this [library](https://github.com/DevLight-Mobile-Agency/InfiniteCycleViewPager). It's not exactly what you want, but it can give you an idea for the start.

Answer (score 0):

Just use margins/paddings in your case:

```
int leftRightPadding = ... ;
int margin = .... ;
viewPager.setClipToPadding(false);
viewPager.setPadding(leftRightPadding, 0, leftRightPadding, 0);
viewPager.setPageMargin(margin);
```

Also check [JazzyViewPager](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager) or equivalent libs for zoom/fade animations.